# Adjusting MS-Word Footer Height?

Tags: vba, footer, ms-word

How can I adjust Microsoft Word's footer height using VBA in Word 2010?

I have tried recording a macro but the height information doesn't get recorded.

Answer (score 3):

It's the `FooterDistance` property of the `PageSetup` object. The example below sets it to 1":

```
With ActiveDocument.PageSetup
    .HeaderDistance = InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .FooterDistance = InchesToPoints(1)
End With
```

Comment: thanx for both the answers ..i will check it out.

Answer (score 1):

The property, that can be read or set is

activedocument.PageSetup.FooterDistance

Unit is in dots based on a 72 DPI, meaning fhat if you set the value to 72, that will give you a 2.54 cm or 1 inch footer

Hope that helps

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see an answer for this, so here is mine:

The height of an empty footer is the BottomMargin minus the FooterDistance.

The margin size determines the maximum size for the whole footer (including the FooterDistance (white space)).

The FooterDistance will determine how close to the edge of the page the text will get rendered.  (be aware that your actual printer margins will chop off stuff that is too close to the edge)

Note: If you already have stuff in your footer and if the text and/or images in the footer has a larger total height - Word will make the footer taller to hold it all.

The sample code below will resize your footer.

```
Dim sHght As Single

With ActiveDocument.PageSetup
  sHght = .BottomMargin     ' get existing margin in points
  .BottomMargin = sHght + 10    ' increase margin (size of space for footer)

  .FooterDistance = CentimetersToPoints(1)  ' set to suit your printer
End With
```